# GCP Logs Exporter is reporting error: db=postgres,user=postgres FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I've changed postgres user password and we started getting error:
db=postgres,user=postgres FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

It happens each second.
[Our log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR59l.png)

I still can't figure it out which service tries to reach our SQL instance with this account.
I tried to set a password we only have, which could be previous one, but it didn't help us.

Did anyone faced the similar situation? Who knows how to fix it?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Best regards, Alexey

Comment: Your description doesn't match your log.  You say you changed the password, but the log says that account doesn't have a password assigned.

Comment: we got similar issue, pg db is isolated from the outside networks, no service is trying to authenticate using the `postgres` user as we have other users defined for each service. Said that, we got these errors from twice a day to several times per hour.

Answer (score 1):

If your database is accessible to the internet, then people will try to log into it.  That is how things are.  You can't police the world.

Their attempts are failing.  So you can just enjoy watching them beat their heads against a wall.  If you don't like the log spam, or if you are afraid you will absent-mindedly set your password to 'b@seb@ll12' someday, you can change your firewall to block the attempts.  You could probably configure logging to log ip addresses too (or, if it is already logged, then inspect that part of the log, which you don't seem to be doing now).

Comment: Cloud SQL connects through VPC, unless [configuring it](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ip) for public IP.

Comment: This instance is private

Comment: @AlexeyKolesaev Is it private enough?  Someone or something is trying to connect, failing, and apparently not telling you about the problem they are having.

Comment: It does't have public ip address. It started happening after i changed the password. So,  i would need to catch an ip or a host which sends requests.

Answer (score 0):

Change [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) `auth-method` in order to request the password, when set.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-password.html